# Проблемы с ghci на малине?

Tags: linux, haskell, raspberry-pi

привет на raspberry установил haskell-platform и ghc но ghci по прежднему комманд нот фаунд хотя ghc есть просит инпунтнуть файл в чем проблема? в самой малине? или для ghci нужно что то отдельно ставить? что то с конфингами в usr/bin?
дист распбиан устанавливал через apt-get install

Comment: вы не указали: во-первых, дистрибутив, во-вторых, каким образом «установили ghc». укажите это всё в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 0):

в [репозитории дистрибутива *raspbian*](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository) самый свежий пакет [ghc](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/ghc/) содержит в каталоге `/usr/bin`:

```
$ file x/usr/bin/ghci
x/usr/bin/ghci: symbolic link to ghci-8.0.1
$ file x/usr/bin/ghci-8.0.1 
x/usr/bin/ghci-8.0.1: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
$ cat x/usr/bin/ghci-8.0.1 
#!/bin/sh
exec "/usr/bin/ghc-8.0.1" --interactive "$@"
```

т.е., присутствует всё необходимое.

пришедшие на ум гипотезы:

1. возможно, пакет *ghc* установился из какого-то «левого» репозитория. проинспектируйте содержимое `/etc/apt/sources.list*` на предмет подключенных репозиториев, удалите ненужные и переустановите пакет.
2. возможно, в переменной окружения `PATH` нет каталога `/usr/bin` (см. вывод `$ echo $PATH`). попробуйте указать полный путь: `$ /usr/bin/ghci`.

если программа `ghc` у вас таки присутствует, попробуйте запустить её с опцией `--interactive`, что обычно и является «запуском ghci», т.е., «ghc в интерактивном режиме».

Comment: скачал архив отсюда https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_0_1 в папке ghc-8.0.1 пишу make говорит сначала выполнить ./configure но на эту команду ругается на ошибку исполнения файла ghc-pwd в итоге cannot determine current directory
почему то с репозитория ставится версия 7.6.3
установил haskell-platform и cabal может как то через них или они наоборот мешают?

Comment: ghci из репозитория не ставится ghc есть в /usr/bin и есть ghc-7.6.3 и ghc-pkg gc-pkg-7.6.3 но все они не каталоги а исполняемые

Comment: А права на запуск скрипта `x/usr/bin/ghci-8.0.1` есть?

Comment: @AlexanderRazorenov ghci* нет вообще есть ghc и только версии 7.6.3 да этот запускается и вполне компилирует

Comment: --interactive не видит ключ ghc

Comment: @yasuoxyu, ghc-7.6.3 — это в jessie. в ghc-7.6.3 действительно не собрана поддержка интерактивной работы. если говорить про raspbian-овский репозиторий, то она собрана в ghc-8.0.1. но этот пакет собран только для версии stretch.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin какие отличия джеси от стреч? на оф сайте вроде последняя джеси тогда почему ghc в стретче более новая?

Comment: @yas, потому что [stretch младше jessie](https://www.debian.org/releases/index.ru.html).

Comment: @yas и новее? почему тогда его не предлагают скачать:? изза того что он еще не совсем стабилен?